# Gradient of second fundamental form

Tags: differential-geometry, surfaces, curvature

In the book I'm reading ("Differential Geometry Curves-Surfaces-Manifolds by Wolfgang Kuhnel") two definitions of prinicpal curvatures directions are presented:

1. The extramum values of $II(X,X)$ under the constraint $I(X,X)=1$
2. The eigenvectors of the shape operator $L$

I'm having some difficulty proving this equivalence. It was also mentioned that the gradient of $II(X,X)$ is simply $LX$ ($L$ operating on $X$). So I thought if I prove that, it follows that (1) holds iff the gradient of $II(X,X)$ is proportional to the gradient of $I(X,X)$ (which is clearly $X$) iff $LX$ and $X$ are proportional iff $X$ is an eigenvector.

- How do I compute the gradient of $II(X,X)$ and show it is equal to $LX$. It seems like it is a simple task that I'm missing some idea or technique.
- I'll be glad to hear of any interesting insights regarding prinicpal curvatures in order to have a better intuition.

Comment: What's $LX$?${}{}$

Comment: The shape operator L operating on the vector X. I'll clarify this

Comment: Do you know that $II(X, Y) = I(LX, Y)$? (might be up to a constant depending on the definition)

Comment: Yes. I am aware of that

Comment: Then the first two equivalence has nothing to do with differential geometry. It's result in linear algebra.

Comment: http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1199852/maximize-the-value-of-vtav

Comment: Thanks. This is indeed just linear algebra

Answer (score 0):

I suppose you could basically identify $T_uf$ as $\mathbb{R}^2$, then you could carry out the calculation in the usual way.
To be more specific about the gradient w.r.t second fundamental form:
\begin{equation}
\frac {\partial}{\partial x_1}<LX,X>=<L'(X)\frac {\partial X}{\partial x_1},X> + <LX,\frac {\partial X}{\partial x_1}>=2<LX,\frac {\partial X}{\partial x_1}>=2<LX,(1,0)^t>  
\end{equation}
which is the first coordinate of $LX$.
Similarly,
$$
\frac {\partial}{\partial x_2}<LX,X>=2<LX,(0,1)^t>
$$
which is the second coordinate of $LX$.
Combine this two equations, you can get the result.

Comment: What is your definition of second fundamental form here?

Comment: the second fundamental form is defined to be the dot product between LX and X on the tangent surface

Comment: and L is defined to be $D\nu$ composite $(Df)^{-1}$ which is known as Weingarten map, here $\nu$ is the Gauss map along $f$